# React button click does not fire event on Iphone & IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, button, event-handling, smartphone

My login button works as designed in all desktop browsers but not on any IOS devices.
If i click/tap on the login button on my smartphone the event does not call the handleSubmit!

```
 handleSubmit = e =>{
   e.preventDefault();
   const errors = this.validate();
   this.setState({errors: errors || {} });
   if(errors) 
    return; 
   //Call Backend
   this.doSubmit()
};`renderButton(label){  
    return  <button type="submit" 
                    disabled={this.validate()}
                    className="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block">{label}
            </button>
};`
```

Comment: Use onTouchStart For event handling

Comment: Hi, already testet with onTouchStart but it’s not working.

Answer (score 0):

## my (non) answer

Apple does this quirky thing where they don't follow standards and they're a terrible company.

It's likely because your button doesn't meet the criteria Apple decided buttons have to meet in order to be buttons. iOS (yes, the OS not the browser) will refuse to bind click events to the button if it "doesn't look like a button".

A lot of people suggest that simply adding `cursor: pointer` as a style will remedy this, but as far as I can tell, this doesn't work. To fix you need to make sure your button "looks like a button" to Apple's standards, which are not documented anywhere, whatever they may be.

### separate suggestion

Your `this.validation()` method will execute on every component update, and since you're using a class component, this is *really* inefficient and will probably cause some performance issues if you're not careful. You should consider having your form validity set as a boolean value in the `state` that only gets updated when the form changes.